# QT How Keep the previous user selected image path in memory for instant loading using QFileDialog

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I am working on a program that takes a file from a directory and when I again try to select the path it will not show the same directory. So, I need to fix the previous path when I choose the next path it will select the previous path.
The first time I will select this path
Example:- C:\Work\Projects\GDCM\gdcm-2.8.6
Next time I will again click to take a file from the same path but it will show the by default path.
Example:- C:\Program Files (x86)
I am using QFileDialog for selecting the path:-

```
QString dir = "";
QFileDialog dia;
dir = dia.getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Select DICOM Directory"), "/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
dia.setDirectory(dir);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of [`QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) specifies the initial directory used by the dialog, and you are not using it correctly.

You are clearly using Windows yet you are always setting the initial directory to a unix home directory `/home`. Rather initialise your string variable and reuse it in subsequent calls.

```
QFileDialog dia;
dir = dia.getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Select DICOM Directory"), dir, QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

Store the return value of `dir` and reuse it the next time you invoke the dialog for the third parameter. You don't need to be using `setDirectory`.

Comment: But here you are fixing the dir path. But I need a dynamic path, not always I m using the same path for selecting the file.

Comment: @AmarYadav Unfortunately you don't understand my answer. Store the return value of `dir` and reuse it the next time for the third parameter of `getExistingDirectory`

Comment: @AmarYadav I've editted my answer to try highlight I'm saying **store and reuse `dir`**. Hope this helps.

Comment: yup, I got this Thanks @acraig5075

Comment: @AmarYadav If I answered your question adequately, please accept it.

Comment: @AmarYadav No problem just click the tick. Read this: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Can you please help me in other topic related to list widget Thumbnails

Comment: I am making a Thumbnail using list widget. That store the bundle of an image. Now I want to display the image with a number just like If I will add 5 images. So, they display the number from 1 to 5.

Comment: @AmarYadav Please ask a new question rather than asking as a comment to another question.

Comment: I am not able to post a new question. My limit is over. So, i am asking here